# How to change table data based on a select option

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to get a little help fetching product attributes from our database, and populating a table row with said attributes, all based on a select option.

I have an html table, with a single row, where the headers are:

1. SKU
2. Item Description
3. Cubic Meters
4. Quantity
5. Price
6. Net Price

The only populated table cell is "SKU", which has a select menu pulling options from our database. The rest of the table is empty. What I am trying to accomplish is to pull table data from our database WHERE sku = 'the value of the select option', and to populate the rest of the html table . So based on the "sku" selection, we need to be able to dynamically fill up the html table with "Item Description", "Cubic Meters", and "Price".

Here is the form page form.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="ERP/styles/check_cs6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //add row function
        function onClickAdd() {
        var tableRow = document.getElementById("tableRow");
        var tableRowClone = tableRow.cloneNode(true);
        tableRow.parentNode.insertBefore(tableRowClone, tableRow.nextSibling);
            }
    </script>
    <script>

        //fetch data
    function showProd(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("prodName").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getprod.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left_column">
        <h1>Purchase Order Form</h1>
        <p>Supplier: 
        <select name="supplier">
            <option value="#">Dave</option>
            <option value="#">Dude</option>
        </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right_column">
        <p>Date: <input type='text' size='6' maxlength='10' /></p>
        <br>
        <p>Ship To This Address:</p>
        <p>123 Fake Street</p>
        <p>Plaza</p>
        <p>Springfield, Simpsons</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="POform">
        <p class="alignLeft">Ship Date: <input type="text" size='6' maxlength='10'></p>
        <p class="alignRight">PO No.: <input type="text" size="6" maxlength="10"></p>
    </div>

<table id="myTable" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>SKU</th>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>CBM</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Net Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tableRow">
                <td width ="10%">
                <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)"> 
        <?php

            $connection = mysql_connect('address', 'user', 'pw');
            mysql_select_db('ADI'); 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT sku FROM inventory");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<option>". $row['sku'] . "</option>";
                                }
        ?>
        </select>
                </td>
                <td width ="50%" id="prodName">

                </td>
                <td width = "10%" id="cbm"></td>
                <td width = "10%" id="qty"><input type="text" size="5"></td>
                <td width = "10%" id="cost"></td>
                <td width = "10%" id="netCost"></td>
                <!--Delete Function doesn't work-->
                <!--<td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow  ('myTable',0)"></td>-->

            </tr>
            <p>
                  <input type="button" name="addButton" value="Add Item" onClick="Javascript:onClickAdd()">
            </p>
        </table>
<br>
<!--<div id="txtHint"><b>info will be listed here...</b></div>-->

</body>
</html>
```

**And this is the form handler page getprod.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ADI');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ADI");
$sql="SELECT prodName, sku, cbm, cost FROM inventory WHERE sku = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


/*
echo "<table width=100%>
<tr>
<th>SKU</th>
<th>Item Description</th>
<th>CBM</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>Net Amount</th>
</tr>";*/
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   // echo "<tr>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row['sku'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prodName'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row['cbm'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row['cost'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row['amt'] . "</td>";
    //echo "</tr>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here is the CSS if this helps formatting:**

```
@charset "utf-8";

#container {    
    width: 968px;    
    background: #FFF;    
    margin: 0 auto;    
    padding-left: 10px;    
    padding-right: 10px;    
    overflow: hidden;       
}    

#left_column{    
    margin-left: 40px;    
    float: left;    
}

#right_column{    
    margin-right: 100px;    
    float: right;    
}

#header h1 {    
    color: #FF0000;    
    font-size: 96px;    
    font-family: sarina, serif;
    margin: 0;    
    float: left;    
}

#header {    
    color: #FFF;    
    background-color: #C8C6C6;    
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;    
}

body {    
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    
    color: #3B3B3B;    
    background-color: #FFF;    
    margin: 0px;    
}

#header h2 {    
    color: #FF0000;    
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;    
    font-size: 30px;    
    font-variant: small-caps;    
    margin-top: 0px;    
    margin-bottom: 0px;    
    padding-top: 15px;    
}

#header a {    
    font-size: 20px;    
    font-weight: bold;    
    font-variant: small-caps;    
    color: #FFF;    
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;    
    width: 100px;    
    display: block;    
}

#header ul {    
    margin: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;    
    list-style-type: none;    
    position: absolute;    
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;    
}

#main_text {    
    background-color: #FFF;    
    width: 300px;    
    position: absolute;    
    right: 60px;    
    bottom: 60px;    
}



#header li {    
    float: left;    
}

#addProduct {    
    margin-left: 125px;    
}

#inventory {    
    margin-left: 20px;;    
}

#purchaseOrders {       

}

a.createNew {    
    float: right;    
} 

#POform{    
    margin-top: 250px;    
}

p.alignRight{    
    float:right;    
    margin-right: 100px;    
}

p.alignLeft{    
    float:left;
    margin-left: 40px;    
}  

#items {    
    margin-top: 325px;    
    margin-left: 40px;    
    margin-right: 100px;    
}

.POinput{    
    width: 50px;    
    float: right;    
}   

#items th{    
    text-align:center;    
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;    
    height: 20px;    
}    

#total{    
    margin-left: 100px;    
    margin-right: 100px;    
}
```

Comment: I hope this is just an example of what are you trying to do, I highly recommend you not to put your query and database connection on the same php file. 

Your life will be more easy if you use JQuery, and maybe a php framework like Laravel.

Hope you have success on your proyect.

Answer (score 0):

In your options you display only the sku, but you also have to set the value attribte. Otherwise when you submit the form, the selected item has an empty value attribute.

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['sku'] . '">'.$row['sku'].'</option>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, wrote additional javascript functions in the form page to fetch single columns from the database based on the select option.

```
//fetches the ProdName
function getProdName(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("prodName").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                //php processor address
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getProd.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    // fetches the CBM
    function getCBM(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("cbm").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                //php processor address
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getCBM.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    //fetches the price
    function getPrice(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
                //php processor address
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getPrice.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
```

Also wrote separate php files to process the sql queries for each column, this one is getProd.php. made one for getCBM (getCBM.php) and for getPrice (getPrice.php) but just changed the sql query select CBM and Price respectively

```
<?php

$q = $_GET['q'];

$con = mysqli_connect('address','user','pw','db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

mysqli_select_db($con,"ADI");
$sql="SELECT prodName, cbm, cost FROM inventory WHERE sku = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    //echo "<td>" . $row['sku'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prodName'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row['cbm'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row['cost'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row['amt'] . "</td>";

}

    /*foreach($result as $row) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['prodName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cbm'] . "</td>";
        }*/

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```